# ERROR !The requested handler 'docker status' was not found in either the main handlers list nor in the listening handlers list

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, ansible, vagrant

I'm using vagrant to create a simulation of a prod cluster in which there a a master and two nodes, my vagrantfile look like this  :

```yaml
IMAGE_NAME = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
N = 2

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.ssh.insert_key = false

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.memory = 1024
        v.cpus = 2
    end
      
    config.vm.define "k8s-master" do |master|
        master.vm.box = IMAGE_NAME
        master.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.10"
        master.vm.hostname = "k8s-master"
        master.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
            ansible.playbook = "kubernetes-setup/master-playbook.yml"
            ansible.extra_vars = {
                node_ip: "192.168.50.10",
            }
        end
    end

    (1..N).each do |i|
        config.vm.define "node-#{i}" do |node|
            node.vm.box = IMAGE_NAME
            node.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.#{i + 10}"
            node.vm.hostname = "node-#{i}"
            node.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
                ansible.playbook = "kubernetes-setup/node-playbook.yml"
                ansible.extra_vars = {
                    node_ip: "192.168.50.#{i + 10}",
                }
            end
        end
    end
end
```

and my master playbook look like this :

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: Install packages that allow apt to be used over HTTPS
    apt:
      name: "{{ packages }}"
      state: present
      update_cache: yes
    vars:
      packages:
      - apt-transport-https
      - ca-certificates
      - curl
      - gnupg-agent
      - software-properties-common

  - name: Add an apt signing key for Docker
    apt_key:
      url: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
      state: present

  - name: Add apt repository for stable version
    apt_repository:
      repo: deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
      state: present

  - name: Install docker and its dependecies
    apt: 
      name: "{{ packages }}"
      state: present
      update_cache: yes
    vars:
      packages:
      - docker-ce 
      - docker-ce-cli 
      - containerd.io
    notify:
      - docker status

  - name: Add vagrant user to docker group
    user:
      name: vagrant
      group: docker
      
  - name: Remove swapfile from /etc/fstab
    mount:
       name: "{{ item }}"
       fstype: swap
       state: absent
    with_items:
        - swap
        - none

   - name: Disable swap
     command: swapoff -a
     when: ansible_swaptotal_mb > 0
     
  - name: Add an apt signing key for Kubernetes
    apt_key:
      url: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
      state: present

  - name: Adding apt repository for Kubernetes
    apt_repository:
      repo: deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
      state: present
      filename: kubernetes.list

  - name: Install Kubernetes binaries
    apt: 
      name: "{{ packages }}"
      state: present
      update_cache: yes
    vars:
      packages:
        - kubelet 
        - kubeadm 
        - kubectl

  - name: Configure node ip
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/default/kubelet
      line: KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--node-ip={{ node_ip }}

  - name: Restart kubelet
    service:
      name: kubelet
      daemon_reload: yes
      state: restarted
  - name: Initialize the Kubernetes cluster using kubeadm
    command: kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address="192.168.50.10" --apiserver-cert-extra-sans="192.168.50.10"  --node-name k8s-master --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16

  - name: Setup kubeconfig for vagrant user
    command: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
     - mkdir -p /home/vagrant/.kube
     - cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf /home/vagrant/.kube/config
     - chown vagrant:vagrant /home/vagrant/.kube/config
  - name: Install calico pod network
    become: false
    command: kubectl create -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.4/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/calico.yaml

  - name: Generate join command
    command: kubeadm token create --print-join-command
    register: join_command

  - name: Copy join command to local file
    local_action: copy content="{{ join_command.stdout_lines[0] }}" dest="./join-command"

  handlers:
    - name: docker status
      service: name=docker state=started
```

while the one used for the nodes is here below :

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: Install packages that allow apt to be used over HTTPS
    apt:
      name: "{{ packages }}"
      state: present
      update_cache: yes
    vars:
      packages:
      - apt-transport-https
      - ca-certificates
      - curl
      - gnupg-agent
      - software-properties-common

  - name: Add an apt signing key for Docker
    apt_key:
      url: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
      state: present

  - name: Add apt repository for stable version
    apt_repository:
      repo: deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
      state: present

  - name: Install docker and its dependecies
    apt: 
      name: "{{ packages }}"
      state: present
      update_cache: yes
    vars:
      packages:
      - docker-ce 
      - docker-ce-cli 
      - containerd.io
    notify:
      - docker status

  - name: Add vagrant user to docker group
    user:
      name: vagrant
      group: docker
  - name: Remove swapfile from /etc/fstab
    mount:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      fstype: swap
      state: absent
    with_items:
      - swap
      - none

  - name: Disable swap
    command: swapoff -a
    when: ansible_swaptotal_mb > 0

  - name: Add an apt signing key for Kubernetes
    apt_key:
      url: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
      state: present

  - name: Adding apt repository for Kubernetes
    apt_repository:
      repo: deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
      state: present
      filename: kubernetes.list

  - name: Install Kubernetes binaries
    apt: 
      name: "{{ packages }}"
      state: present
      update_cache: yes
    vars:
      packages:
        - kubelet 
        - kubeadm 
        - kubectl

  - name: Configure node ip
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/default/kubelet
      line: KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--node-ip={{ node_ip }}

  - name: Restart kubelet
    service:
      name: kubelet
      daemon_reload: yes
      state: restarted

  - name: Initialize the Kubernetes cluster using kubeadm
    command: kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address="192.168.50.10" --apiserver-cert-extra-sans="192.168.50.10"  --node-name k8s-master --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16

  - name: Copy the join command to server location
    copy: src=join-command dest=/tmp/join-command.sh mode=0777

  - name: Join the node to cluster
    command: sh /tmp/join-command.sh
```

but when I launch my vagrant everything goes well until the installation of docker task on the node where I am facing this issue :

```sh
Vagrant has automatically selected the compatibility mode '2.0'
according to the Ansible version installed (2.9.6).

Alternatively, the compatibility mode can be specified in your Vagrantfile:
https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_common.html#compatibility_mode

    node-1: Running ansible-playbook...

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Distribution Ubuntu 16.04 on host node-1 should use 
/usr/bin/python3, but is using /usr/bin/python for backward compatibility with 
prior Ansible releases. A future Ansible release will default to using the 
discovered platform python for this host. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/
2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information. This 
feature will be removed in version 2.12. Deprecation warnings can be disabled 
by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
ok: [node-1]

TASK [Install packages that allow apt to be used over HTTPS] *******************
changed: [node-1]
[WARNING]: Updating cache and auto-installing missing dependency: python-apt

TASK [Add an apt signing key for Docker] ***************************************
changed: [node-1]

TASK [Add apt repository for stable version] ***********************************
changed: [node-1]

TASK [Install docker and its dependecies] **************************************
*****ERROR! The requested handler 'docker status' was not found in either the main handlers list nor in the listening handlers list
Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.*****
```

Anyone have a clue what could be the reason, I have tried to change the syntax but still I don't think it is a typo problem ?

Comment: Have you considered using [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io) for this?  That is a prepackaged tool, that runs inside a Docker container, that can run a simulated multi-node Kubernetes cluster for this sort of testing.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I will do some other time but still the idea was tor try vagrant + kube + ansible

Comment: You are deploying your master and nodes with two totally independent playbooks. The one for nodes does not declare any handlers. Hence Ansible not finding one is totally expected.

Answer (score 0):

As @zeitounator said in his command I forgot to add the handler part in the nodes configuration playbook, once it was added everything went well.